# Using lodash to return an array of unique values while removing non unique

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm trying to return the survey the visitor hasn't voted on, by survey_id. Using the example arrays below, I would expect survey_id: 4 to be returned.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Here are my example arrays:

```js
// Survey Object
[{
  survey_id: 1,
  name: 'Survey 1",
  question: "This is a survey question"
}, {
  survey_id: 2,
  name: 'Survey 2",
  question: "This is a another survey question"
}, {
  survey_id: 3,
  name: 'Survey 3",
  question: "This is a another 3 survey question"
}, {
  survey_id: 4,
  name: 'Survey 4",
  question: "This is a another 4 survey question"
}]

// Votes
[{
  vote_id: 11,
  visitor_token: "aDe4GggAe3",
  survey_id: 1
}, {
  vote_id: 12,
  visitor_token: "aDe4GggAe3",
  survey_id: 2
}, {
  vote_id: 13,
  visitor_token: "aDe4GggAe3",
  survey_id: 3
}]
```

Comment: Use [differenceBy](https://lodash.com/docs/#differenceBy) : `_.differenceBy(surveys, votes,'survey_id')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The accepted answer has O(n^2) time complexity.</strike> If performance matters, linear operations nested within each other should be avoided -- if favoring terseness of code, @S.D.'s answer is cleaner. Here is a version with vanilla JavaScript and linear time O(n) complexity.

```
function surveysWithNoVotes(surveyList, voteList) {
  var surveyIds = surveyList.map(function(survey) {
    return survey.survey_id
  })
  var votedForIdsMap = voteList.reduce(function(memo, vote) {
    memo[vote.survey_id] = vote.survey_id
  }, {})
  return surveyIds.filter(function(id) {
    return !votedForIdsMap[id]
  })
}
```

Comment: I'm new to programming and wasn't familiar with O(n^2), after doing some research to understand it, I see that you are correct. I've switched your answer to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `_.filter` and `_.find` to apply a filter function to your survey collection, which filters out surveys when matching `survey_id` is found in votes collection. See this sample `getUnansweredSurveys` function:

```
function getUnansweredSurveys(surveys, votes) { 
  return _.filter(surveys, function(survey) { 
    return !_.find(votes, {survey_id: survey.survey_id})
  }) 
}
```